# OCaml :: Read a list of integers from console and print back

Tags: ocaml

I have a list of integers (I don't know how many) on the console like so,

```
3
10
9
8
2
7
5
1
3
0
```

I want to read them into a list and print them back in order as they were read in. So far I have tried the following but it does not work.

```
let rec read_nums arr = (*takes an initial array*)
     try 
         let i = read_int () in (*read next integer*)
              read_nums (i::arr) (*append to array and recurse*)
     with End_of_file -> arr (*return array if everything has been read*)

let input = (read_nums []) (*call the function*)

(*destruct the list, print head, recurse*)
let rec print_input array = match arr with 
   | hd::tl -> (print_int hd; print_input tl;)
   | [] -> ()

(*call the function*)
print_input input
```

Fails with the following error

```
File "solution.ml", line 15, characters 12-17:
Error: Syntax error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future:

- Minimize your code. The same error is reproducible in two lines.
- Remove line numbers. They make it hard to paste and run the code.

About the error: it seems OCaml's `let` binding has form `let ... in expr`. The following works:

```
let rec read_nums arr = (*takes an initial array*)
    try 
        let i = read_int () in (*read next integer*)
            read_nums (i::arr) (*append to array and recurse*)
    with End_of_file -> arr (*return array if everything has been read*)
    in

let input = (read_nums [1; 2]) in (*call the function*)

(*destruct the list, print head, recurse*)
let rec print_input arr = match arr with 
    | hd::tl -> (print_int hd; print_input tl;)
    | [] -> ()
    in

print_input input
```

Comment: OCaml has both `let ... = ... in ...` and `let ... = ...`, and there is no need to write all `let`-bindings in the first manner. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53930408/5989200) for another (and I think more normal) solution.

Answer (score 4):

Add `let () = ...` before toplevel expressions.

Your syntax error is came from the last line:

```
let rec print_input arr =
  match arr with
  | hd::tl -> (print_int hd; print_input tl)
  | [] -> ()

print_input input  (* this line! *)
```

Here, it looks like `print_input input` is a function application in the top level, however, it also can be a constructor application `() print_input` as below:

```
let rec print_input arr =
  match arr with
  | hd::tl -> (print_int hd; print_input tl)
  | [] -> () print_input input
```

Roughly speaking, the OCaml parser firstly thinks it's a constructor application, but then `input` remains alone, so an error occurs.

To avoid this, you can use `let () = ...`:

```
let rec print_input arr =
  match arr with
  | hd::tl -> (print_int hd; print_input tl)
  | [] -> ()

let () =
  print_input input
```

With this convention, all toplevel expressions disappear. Also, this makes our programs safer since it requires that the type of the returned expression is `unit`.

For details, please see this OCaml tutorial: [The Structure of OCaml Programs](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/structure_of_ocaml_programs.html)